# Is it true that a coercive Riemannian metric implies geodesic completeness?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, geodesic

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and let $Q:U \to S_{++}^n$ be a smooth positive definite matrix valued function on $U$. Suppose also that as $x \to \partial U$, we have $\|Q\|_2 \to \infty$. That is, $Q(.)$ is coercive on $U$. Define the Riemannian metric on $U$ at $x \in U$ as $g_x(v,w):= v^TQ(x)w$. My question is, is $(U,g)$ geodesically complete? My intuition says yes, since the metric explodes near the boundary, so geodesics will never “pierce” it. They will keep traversing towards the boundary, but doing so at slower and slower “speeds” in the Euclidean, not Riemannian, sense.

Comment: Offhand, I don’t see why. If $Q$ explodes only in directions tangent to the boundary of $U$ but not the normal direction, seems like the metric will be incomplete. But if you assume the lowest eigenvalue explodes, then the metric will be complete.

Comment: Did not you ask this question on MO? The hint is the same: Consider the 1-dimensional case and find counter examples for both finite and infinite intervals as your domains.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I did consider the hint and could not find any counter examples.

Comment: @Deane That is a convincing argument, but is it enough to imply that a geodesic would hit the boundary? Maybe it wouldn't?

Comment: Do you know any smooth positive function on $(0,1)$ which diverges to infinity at $0, 1$ but has finite integral? One usually learns such examples in calculus when computing improper integrals.

Comment: @MoisheKohan $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}$ satisfies this.

Comment: I would have used a rational function of $\sqrt x$ instead but it does not matter. Now define a Riemannian metric on $(0,1)$ as $f^2(x)dx^2$ and check that it is incomplete.

Comment: @MoisheKohan How can I check that it is incomplete? Intuitively, it does not seem to be incomplete.

Comment: How do you compute the length of a path? You integrate of course. Now, check that $(0,1)$ has finite length with respect to the new metric. It requires no intuition, just compute.

Comment: I am assuming that you know at least one definition of completeness of a Riemannian metric. Any definition will tell you that finite integral implies incompleteness.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I computed it, and $(0,1)$ has infinite length. The length of $(0,1)$ is $\int_0^1 \sqrt{f''(t)}dt$. This is using the curve $\gamma(t)=t$ and the length equation $L(\gamma):=\int_0^1 \sqrt{\gamma'(t)f''(t)\gamma'(t)}dt$. Here, $f''(t)=\frac{3}{4t^{5/2}}+\frac{3}{4(1-t)^{5/2}}$.

Comment: I see what your problem is: You do not have the right formula for the length of a path with respect to a Riemannian metric. What does your textbook say?

Comment: @MoisheKohan I do have the correct formula: $L(\gamma) = \int_0^1 \sqrt{\langle \gamma'(t), \gamma'(t) \rangle_{\gamma(t)}} dt$

Comment: Ok, that's correct, but then where did $f''(t)$ come from?

Comment: The correct formula for length is $\int_0^1 f(t)dt$.

Comment: My bad I confused $f(t)$ with a Barrier function rather than the metric itself.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I guess this implies we need more than a coercive Riemannian metric. I'm curious how fast things have to explode at the boundary to ensure geodesic completeness, if even that is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $f(x)=x^{-1/2} + (1-x)^{-1/2}$. A direct computation shows that
$$
\int_0^1 f(x)dx= 2+ 2=4<\infty.
$$
Now, consider the Riemannian metric $ds^2=f^2(x)dx^2$ on $(0,1)$. This metric has the property that
$$
\lim_{x\to 0+} f(x)=\infty= \lim_{x\to 1-} f(x),
$$
i.e. the metric is coercive. But the total length of $(0,1)$ with respect to the Riemannian metric $f^2(x)dx^2$ is
$$
\int_0^1 f(x)dx<\infty. 
$$
Hence, the metric is incomplete. Thus, coercivity does not imply completeness. I think (but I did not check) that to get completeness you need a metric such that
$$
||Q^{-1}(x)||=O \left(d(x, \partial U)\right), x\in U. 
$$